# Undefined Variable : in View

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hello everyone i want to ask why my controller couldn't be load on view? But I Already Declared the variable this is my code

In This View the data not Showing and give Error Undefined Variable but already declared

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" data-user="user" value="<?php echo $jabatan->nama_jabatan; ?>" readonly>
</div>
```

This Is My Controller I Think in There Not Loading The Data

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('jabatan_model'); //sejajarlevel
        $this->load->model('jenis_biaya_model'); //sejajarbook
        $this->load->model('penerimaan_model'); //sejajarcustomer
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('id_user') != Null)
        {
            $id = $this->session->userdata('id_jabatan');
            $data = array(
                'kode_bayar' => $this->pembayaran_model->invoice_no(),
                'total' => $this->show_total(),
                'jabatan' => $this->jabatan_model->jabatan_getById($id)->row(),
                'jenis_biaya' => $this->jenis_biaya_model->jenis_biaya_getAll(),
                'penerimaan' => $this->penerimaan_model->penerimaan_getAll(),
            );
            $this->load->view('admin/pembayaran/v_Pembayaran', $data);
        } else { 
            $load = $this->load->view('auth/login'); 
            echo '<script language=JavaScript>alert("Anda Belum Login, Silahkan Login") 
            onclick=location.href="auth" </script>';
        }

    }
```

This Is My Model

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Pembayaran_model extends CI_model
{

    public function jenis_biaya_getAll()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM jenis_biaya");
        return $query;
    }

    public function jenis_biaya_getById($id)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM jenis_biaya where id_jenis_biaya=$id");
        return $query;
    }
    public function min_stock($qty, $id_jenis_biaya) 
    { 
        $query = $this->db->query("UPDATE jenis_biaya SET stock=stock-$qty 
            Where id_jenis_biaya=$id_jenis_biaya"); 
        return $query; 
    }

    public function plus_stock($qty, $id_jenis_biaya) 
    { 
        $query = $this->db->query("UPDATE jenis_biaya SET stock=stock+$qty 
            Where id_jenis_biaya=$id_jenis_biaya"); 
        return $query; 
    }

    public function invoice_no() 
    { 
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(pembayaran_id) as invoice_no from pembayaran"); 
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) { 
            $row = $query->row(); 
            $n = ((int) $row->invoice_no) + 1; 
            $no = sprintf("%09s", $n); 
        } else { 
            $no = sprintf("%09s", 1); 
        } 
        $kode_bayar = "BYR" . $no; 
        return $kode_bayar; 
    }

    public function pembayaran_insert($table, $data) 
    { 
        $query = $this->db->insert($table, $data); 
        return $query; 
    } 
    public function pembayaran_last_id() 
    { 
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(pembayaran_id) as pembayaran_id FROM pembayaran"); 
        return $query->row(); 
    } 

    public function d_pembayaran_insert($table, $data) 
    { 
        $query = $this->db->insert($table, $data); 
        return $query; 
    }
}
```

Thanks For The Help

Comment: in your model you need to return a result, e.g. return query->result() or return query->row(), see [Generating Query Results](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#generating-query-results)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php print_r($jabatan); ?>
```

Use above line to check whether array is coming from controller or not.

Comment: Still Can't Showing Result

Comment: it means your modal is not responding with proper result, try to check for that.